# Left Join to find difference between two tables with different id

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables: `table_old` and `table_new`, both with columns:

```
name, 
surname, 
birthdate 
birthplace
```

plus others info columns. Both have an `id` column that doesn't match between tables. Some records are changed over time between tables, and now I need to have a third table with the records that are changed (added or deleted) between tables.

So I need to compare tables with `name` and `surname` and `birthdate` and `birthplace`.

I think that I have to use a Left Join, but I'm not sure abut syntax. Any help?

Comment: are you wanting to find records in Old not in new, new not in old or both?  Additionally a left join seems reasonable; have you tried one?

Comment: I think the join predicate will be difficult to build as the ids columns don't match, and the values of the other columns changes over time. In short, the join criteria would not any sense.

Comment: Need to find both, but if I find new not in old its easy to find old not in new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not actually support a formal `OUTER JOIN` operation, but we can simulate one using a union of two joins.  Use a full outer join to include records from both tables which do not match to anything in the other table:

```
SELECT t1.*, 'table one' AS missing
FROM table_old t1
LEFT JOIN table_new t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name           AND
       t1.surname = t2.surname     AND
       t1.birthdate = t2.birthdate AND
       t1.birthplace = t2.birthplace
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*, 'table two'
FROM table_old t1
RIGHT JOIN table_new t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name           AND
       t1.surname = t2.surname     AND
       t1.birthdate = t2.birthdate AND
       t1.birthplace = t2.birthplace
WHERE t1.name IS NULL;
```

My criteria for claiming that a record is out of date is that any one of the fields does not match.  That is, if three fields agree, but one does not, then I do not count it as a match.

Follow the link below for a running demo.  You might be able to refine my answer and make it easier to group together pairs of records which are logically the same, but that would take more work.

## Demo

Comment: @xQbert You're right, and I should have tested it.  In any case, I added a demo to the question just now.